# Display FlightTrip and FlightStop Details using views

Tags: sql, relational-database

I would like to extract data from a specific table . However the constrain is i need to u 2 relational views to get the data. I am able to get the data without using view, but the requirement is to use views. And i new to db. I hope you guys can help me. Thus i think i need to use data from 2 tables. But from my understanding i dont think i need to use 2 tables. Hope u guys cand advice. As i said earlier i need to use 2 views to extract the data.

```
 FlightTripNo Departure Destination FinalDestination
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 05 Singapore Bangalore Chennai
 03 Sdyney Auckland
```

This is the following table.

```
FLIGHTTRIP( FlightTripNo,PlaneNo)
PRIMARY KEY (FlightTripNo),

( 1, JET348)
( 2, TR1313)
( 3, TR287)
( 4, MY871P)
( 5, SQ777)
( 6, AI322X)
```

FLIGHTSTOP TABLE

```
FLIGHTSTOP(  FlightTripNo, FlightStopNo, DEPARTURE, DESTINATION )    
PRIMARY KEY (FlightTripNo, FlightStopNo)
UNIQUE UNIQUE(FlightTripNo, DEPARTURE, DESTINATION)
FOREIGN KEY (FlightTripNo) REFERENCES FLIGHTTRIP(FlightTripNo)

INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 1, 1, 'Singapore', 'Malaysia');
INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 1, 2, 'Malaysia', 'Chennai');
INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 1, 3, 'Chennai', 'Bangalore');
INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 3, 1, 'Syndey', 'Auckland');
INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 5, 1, 'Singapore', 'Bangalore');
INSERT INTO FLIGHTSTOP VALUES( 5, 2, 'Bangalore', 'Chennai');
......
Total 400 records
```

This how far i have done without using views. But i need to use views. And 2 view. Please advice.

```
 SELECT FLIGHTSTOP.FlightTripNo,FLIGHTSTOP.FlightStopNo, FLIGHTSTOP.DEPARTURE AS ORIGIN,  FLIGHTSTOP.DESTINATION AS DESTINATION1, T2.DESTINATION AS DESTINATION2
 FROM FLIGHTSTOP LEFT JOIN FLIGHTSTOP T2 ON FLIGHTSTOP.FlightTripNo = T2.FlightTripNo AND   FLIGHTSTOP.DEPARTURE = T2.DEPARTURE
 WHERE FLIGHTSTOP.FlightTripNo IN (SELECT FlightTripNo FROM FLIGHTSTOP
                GROUP BY FlightTripNo
                HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
                ORDER BY FLIGHTSTOP.FlightTripNo;
```

Comment: Did they give you a view to use? Typically in a RDBMS, a view is simply a SQL statement saved in the DB metadata that exposes a table or a join to a consumer so  the consumer doesn't have to join or filter the tables themselves. I would go back to the folks giving you these requirements and find out what they want the views for...

Comment: @NWest The requirement is to create at least 2 relational views in
implementation of this task.

Comment: @NWest But my piece of code works without using views

Comment: If your SQL works, then you need to address this with the client. Maybe they just want you to create two views on top of the two tables, then have your SQL read off the views instead of the tables directly. Regardless, if your result set is what the client needs, then you need to explain that to them - I don't think SO can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @NWest view is a database object like table. But it does not store any data by itself. The concept of view is actually storing an SQL statement. Storing complex sql statement using a view helps for complex queries more easier. Additionally it features that you can directly execute SELECT statement on a view. For example:

```
create view emp_dept as select empno, ename, sal, dept.deptno, dname from emp, dept
where emp.deptno = dept.deptno and deptno=10;
```

Now a view is created with the name emp_dept. You can query on the view by the following statement just like a table. And you can join this view with another view or table.

```
select ename, sal from emp_dept where sal>2000.
```

I hope you got the idea of a view. Now use this concept for your example.